# How to preserve the original extension after multiple files manipulation

Tags: filenames, imagemagick, file-types

This follow is a useful command to add a border to multiple images (require ImageMagick package): `convert -border 5x5 -bordercolor "#008000" *.png imgs`
The result is that the new files will be named something like `imgs-0`, `imgs-1`, `imgs-2` ecc. I would like instead: `imgs-0.png`, `imgs-1.png`, `imgs-2.png`, or, even better, `NEW*.png`.

Answer (score 4):

Use `+adjoin` and `%d` to write to multiple files with a more utile naming template:

```
 convert -border 5x5 -bordercolor "#008000" *.png +adjoin NEW_%d.png
```